# How to make the light from the flashlight in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, light, volumetrics

How to make the light from the flashlight in Blender Cycles?

The Emission node doesn’t give volumetric light:

[image]

I'll use it in animation, example:

[image].

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/how-can-a-light-cone-volumetric-be-setup-with-cycles and also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30695/lighting-specific-objects-in-cycles-with-volumetric-atmosphere

Comment: here is a posibility too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xw9FALJ7fvo

Answer (score 0):

the volumetric part of the light could be a parented object on his own, with appropriate nodes and textures for emission, transparency, translucency, maybe in a separate layer to be blurred, alpha overed and color corrected.

Comment: Can you show me concrete nodes & settings of the volume light?